# Stop flex child from growing when text contents are too long

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex layout which looks like this:

[image]

That's fine but when the product description is very long, I want to hide the overflow and show an ellipsis.

There is a flex container with the class `info-container` which has 2 flex children - `left` (30%) and `right` (70%). The `right` div is itself a flex container. The problem is this `div` expands when the text is too long:

[image]

The HTML is:

```
<div class="info-container top">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="item-image-container">
      <div class="item-image" > 
        <img height="75" width="75" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg" /> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h2>
     header
    </h2>

    <div class="product-description">
      product desc stuff product desc stuff stuff product desc stuff stuff 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
.info-container {
      margin-left: 300px;
      display: flex;
      flex: 0 0 100%;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      width: 400px;
      border: 1px red solid;
      padding: 3px;
}

.left {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 30%;
}


.right {
  flex: 70%;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  min-width:0;
}

.product-description {
  min-width:0;
  font-sixe: 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

The jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bky3gk63/2/).

How can I ensure the `right div` does not expand if the text is too long, and instead an ellipsis is shown?

Comment: Add `min-width: 0` to `.right`. By default, it's `auto`, so `flex-shrink` can't make the flex item narrower than its content. Also, change `flex` values from percentages to just numbers.

Comment: instead flex:30%;/flex:70%; use width : 30%/width:70% (or max-width)

Comment: Can you explain why you need a flexbox if you don't want it to be flexible?

Comment: `.right` div is a flex item, not flex container; there is a typo `font-sixe`; The soln should be restricting `.right` div `overflow:hidden`... (not tested)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm a big proponent of flex box, your usage of it here doesn't seem appropriate.

- You have a lot of fixed width elements (`img`: 75px, `.info-container: 400px`)
- You have flex parent properties assigned to children (`justify-content`, `align-items`)

You can simplify this a lot with just a floated container for your image if using so many fixed widths is a criteria of this situation.

**Simple float example:**

```css
.info-container {
  max-width: 400px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #ddd;
  min-height: 75px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  min-width:0;
  margin: 0;
}

.product-description {
  font-size: 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-container top">
  <div class="left">
  <img height="75" width="75" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h2>header</h2>
    <div class="product-description">
      Product desc stuff product desc stuff stuff product desc stuff stuff product desc stuff stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

Flex box is meant to be fluid.  A more appropriate use of it might look like the following, where we allow the containers and the content to flex and fill their space appropriately.

**Flex Box example:**

```css
.info-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px red solid;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #ddd;
  min-height: 75px;
}

.left {
  flex: 30%;
}

.right {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  min-width: 0;
}

.left img {
  max-width: 100%;
} 

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  min-width:0;
  margin: 0;
}

.product-description {
  font-size: 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-container top">
  <div class="left">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h2>header</h2>
    <div class="product-description">
      Product desc stuff product desc stuff stuff product desc stuff stuff product desc stuff stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the `min-width: 0` on the `.right` flex child. This is used to ensure the overflow works correctly ([see reference here](https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/)), and that any fixed widths both in the CSS and the markup are removed.